# Is $r.b*=b*A$ true?

Tags: vectors, matrix-equations

Let $a, b \in \Bbb C^n$ and $A\in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$. If $b^*\cdot a=1$ and $r=b^*\cdot A\cdot a$, is it true that: $r\cdot b^*=b^*A$?

Comment: Does $*$ refer to the conjugate-transpose?

Comment: Yes, ∗ refer to the conjugate-transpose

Comment: My question is may be too simple.
I'm not very familiar with matrix-vector expressions

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no.  For an example where this doesn't work, take
$$
a = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the conjugate transpose, we get
$$(rb^*)^* = b(b^*Aa)^* = ba^*A^*b$$
Which we need to be equal to
$$(b^*A)^* = A^*b$$
Since matrix multiplication is associative, we can explicitly write
$$ ba^*A^*b = ((ba^*)A^*)b$$
Then, we have the desired equality for all $b$ if and only if  $$ba^* = I$$ for all $b$, which is not possible. Thus, the equality doesn't hold for all $b$.

Comment: Тhanks a lot for quick answers.